# How to create a vignette mask that follows object and always faces camera in shader nodes

Tags: shader-nodes, masking

I've got a block moving along a treadmill.

[image]

Is there any way I can create a circular mask that always faces the camera and sits at the centre of the object?

[image]

I've trying to overlay a video on top of the block's regular texture., like this:

[image: Where black is the regular texture and Dr Strange is the video that faces the camera]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)